# Repro for missed rows during Allocation Order Scan + Page Splits

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, isolation-level

In Read Uncommitted, an index scan can execute as an allocation order scan. If a page split occurs during the scan, it is possible that a row will be read twice if it moves to a later position in the allocation order. I have been able to reproduce this.

This example, from Brent Ozar, will consistently demonstrate rows being read more than once:

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/

It is also reported that a row can be missed when a page split occurs. The inference is that the relocated row is moved to an earlier place in the allocation order. I have not been able to reproduce this.

Does anyone have a repro for this phenomenon ? Ideally something that shows it consistently.

Comment: Brent's repro shows both repeated rows and missed rows (there are 299,611 rows in the `dbo.Users` table in StackOverflow2010, the last visible result shows a count of 299,398).

Comment: Thanks Josh - for me I had to expand the sample data somewhat, but having done that it does indeed demonstrate the missed rows phenomena,